# RouteMapper is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having a issues when it comes to using the React Router V6. Basically I am trying to map throughout the file which contains the routes (paths, components etc..). The issue I am having is that I am trying to map those routes inside another route because I am using a layout (Have to use that layout since 2 routes do not that layout so that is why). Everything works when I am mapping the `<Route/>` component since that component is from `react-router-dom`, but when I am using the helper component called `RouteMapper` this is the problem I encounter.

##### File with routes

```
import { Home, About, Profile} from "../../pages";

export const generalRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    component: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    exact: true,
    component: <About/>,
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    exact: true,
    component: <Profile />,
  },
];
```

##### RouteMapper.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const RouteMapper = ({ route }) => {
  return (
    <Route path={route.path} element={route.component} exact={route.exact} />
  );
};

export default RouteMapper;
```

##### General.jsx

```
const General = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          {generalRoutes?.map((route, index) => {
            return <RouteMapper route={route} key={index} />;
          })}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default General;
```

Here I am getting an error. I am using the **helper component** since I will also implement authentication so it would be much easier for me to implement it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render `Route` components directly and the `RouteMapper` component can't be the child of the `Routes` or `Route` components.

You can map `generalRoutes` to `Route` components though, especially considering all it's doing is proxying props to a `Route` component.

```
const General = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
        {generalRoutes?.map((route) => (
          <Route
            key={route.path}
            path={route.path}
            element={route.component}
          />
        ))}
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

You might find reconfiguring your `generalRoutes` into a full-fledged route config using the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useroutes) hook might be a little easier to use.

Example:

```
import { Home, About, Profile } from "../../pages";

export const appRoutes = [
  // Routes rendered into Layout outlet
  {
    element: <Layout />
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/about",
        element: <About/>,
      },
      ....

      // Routes rendered into an Auth outlet
      {
        element: <AuthLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/profile",
            element: <Profile />,
          },
          ....
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  // Routes not rendered into Layout
  {
    path: "/other",
    element: <Profile />,
  },
  ....
];
```

...

```
const routes = useRoutes(appRoutes);

...

return (
  ...
  {routes}
  ...
);
```